# Does php mail function acts as an email client?

Tags: php, smtp, html-email, email, smtpclient

I am working on an email sending script in plain PHP

I am curious about this PHP mail function is this function is just an email client or I am configuring it wrong?

Comment: No its an api to your mta.. it does not fetch email.

Comment: You need first install a `MTA` on your server, maybe `sendmail`, then php mail function will put the mail message to the `MTA` & send the mail for you.

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/64002648562362b97fcb78b68366b1b2118ffd5b/ext/standard/mail.c#L469